# Execute Sql Query in MVC

Tags: sql, model-view-controller

i need to execute this query in MVC

```
SELECT agents.*,
       zone.State AS ZONE,
       zonedistrict.District
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM ABC('04-01-2018' ,'04-08-2018', '%%', '%%', '', '', '', '', '')) agents
INNER JOIN SW_TBL_STATE ZONE ON agents.State=ZONE.State_Id
INNER JOIN SW_TBL_STATEDISTRICT zonedistrict ON agents.District=zonedistrict.District_Id;
```

how do i execute it. i am actually new in this stuff.

Comment: use some ORM or using ADO.Net

Comment: MVC is what for you ?

Comment: i am using _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() and i need to pass the dates parameter, so how do i use it.

Comment: Could you post your code  about  `_ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`?

Comment: i tried this but its says cannot implicitly convert int to generic list

`var sql = "Select agents.*, zone.State as Zone, zonedistrict.District from(Select * from ABC(@FromDate , @ToDate, '%%', '%%', '', '', '', '', ''))agents inner join SW_TBL_STATE zone on agents.State = zone.State_Id inner join SW_TBL_STATEDISTRICT zonedistrict on agents.District = zonedistrict.District_Id";
            model.agentList = _ent.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
                new SqlParameter("@FromDate", model.FromDate),
                new SqlParameter("@ToDate", model.ToDate));`

Comment: omg edit your question, insert the code in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: "MVC" ("Model-View-Controller") is a design pattern to structure applications. It's nothing where you can execute SQL statements. Please tell us which programming language, programming environment, frameworks and database product ("SQL" is just a query language, not a database product) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use below sample

```
var innerJoinQuery =
          from cust in customers
          join dist in distributors on cust.City equals dist.City
           select new { CustomerName = cust.Name, DistributorName = dist.Name };
```